# How can I define external API function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

In my project, I need to add an external API function, for example:

```
SELECT c.name
   FROM c,s 
WHERE
   checkresult(c.name);
```

The function `checkresult()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and in this function I need to call some third party API function. How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What kind of "third party API"? C/C++? Java? Pascal? a WebService?

Comment: C/C++ API, it's a local program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this.

One is to use a procedure language. That can use much about any language you want after installing the language in question:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createlanguage.html

Postgres is typically compiled with Perl and Python languages. So after installing e.g. plerlu (since you need remote access functions), you could do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcname (argument-types) RETURNS return-type AS $$
    # PL/Perl function body
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plperl-funcs.html

The other way is to use a foreign data wrapper:

[http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign%5fdata%5fwrappers)

These need(ed?) to be written in C. There are multiple examples in the above-referenced page. For an example that pulls from a third party API, see the Twitter fdw for instance:

```
SELECT from_user, created_at, text FROM twitter WHERE q = '#postgresql';
```

[http://pgxn.org/dist/twitter_fdw/](http://pgxn.org/dist/twitter%5ffdw/)

`https://github.com/umitanuki/twitter_fdw` (SO breaks the link by encoding the `_`)

For a more generic one, see the www fdw:

```
select * from www_fdw_geocoder_google where address='1600 Amphitheatre Parkway,Mountain View, CA';
```

[http://pgxn.org/dist/www_fdw/](http://pgxn.org/dist/www%5ffdw/)

`https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/` (SO breaks the link by encoding the `_`)